# Distinct in foreach loop. To many result because of two loops

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I've a custom system that provides adding new information in custom columns.
I've two tables in my database. One for my value data and the second for the columns (data fieds).

[image]

Above you see a image from my form that is build by custom data fields with data per field.
Only in my for each i get for every data a extra loop so that is why i got from every data field two. How can I fix this?

```
<?php foreach ($list as $key => $value) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($dataList as $data) { ?>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-xl-12">
                <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                    <label><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></label>
                    <?php if($key == $data['name']) { ?>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value_<?php echo trim($data['name']); ?>" value="<?php echo trim($data['value']); ?>" required>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value_<?php echo trim($data['name']); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo ucfirst($key); ?>">
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

`$list` you'll find a list of data fields and in `$dataList` you'll find records of data.

Database structure:

data:

```
['id','hash','field_id','value']
```

Example of data:

```
['id' => 1, 'hash' => 123, 'field_id' => 1, 'value' => 'food']
```

Fields:

```
['id','name']
```

Example of fields:

```
['id' => 1, 'name' => 'firstname']
```

Below you'll find the foreach variables:

```
$data = processing('read', 'data JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id', ['data.value,data.uid,fields.name,data.id,fields.category_id'], 'uid = "' . trim($_GET['datalist']) . '"', true);
$dataItem = processing('read', 'data JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id', ['fields.category_id'], 'uid = "' . trim($_GET['datalist']) . '"');
$fieldList = processing('read', 'fields', ['name'], 'category_id = "'. trim($dataItem['category_id']) . '"',true);
$list = [];
foreach($fieldList as $key => $value) {
    $list[$value['name']] = $value['name'];
}
```

Update:

I've update my own question because the other answers didn't resolved my problem. The only problem on my answer is, that when I update it doesnt look at the id of the item but at the name, so i can't save two items with the same name.

```
<?php foreach ($dataItems as $key => $value) { ?>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-default">
            <label><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo ucfirst($key); ?>" class="form-control" name="<?php echo trim($key); ?>" value="<?php echo trim($value); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

method:

```
public function getDataListItems(int $category, array $list) {
global $dbh;

$query = 'SELECT data.value, data.uid, fields.name FROM data JOIN fields ON data.field_id = fields.id WHERE fields.category_id = "' . trim($category) . '" ORDER BY uid';

$sql = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sql->execute();
$values = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($values as $row) {
    if (!isset($items[$row['uid']])) {
        $items[$row['uid']] = array_fill_keys($list, '');  // if it needs to dynamically generated
        $items[$row['uid']]['uid'] = $row['uid'];
    }
    $items[$row['uid']][$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}
return $items;  
}
```

Return:

```
  array (
  '7d1f4f8e906245f' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'Bettina',
    'Achternaam' => 'Les',
    'Initialen' => 'pop',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245f',
  ),
  '7d1f4f8e906245g' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'Simone',
    'Achternaam' => '',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245g',
  ),
  '7d1f4f8e906245l' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'test',
    'Achternaam' => 'Kül',
    'Initialen' => 'lol',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245l',
  ),
  '7d1f4f8e906245s' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => 'Joshua',
    'Achternaam' => 'Mas',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => '7d1f4f8e906245s',
  ),
  'gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn' => 
  array (
    'Voornaam' => '',
    'Achternaam' => 'Hello',
    'Initialen' => '',
    'uid' => 'gGcYEJdRYJ1vqcn',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Well, that's what you're telling your application to do. For *each* data field you iterate *each* record. The number of fields repeated will match the number of records you have. Can you please add more details about your database structure? It seems odd.

Comment: See update of my question!

Comment: Can you fix it ?

Comment: How do you get the values of `$list` and `$dataList` before looping? I'm guessing they're queries. Can you show those?

Comment: I've add it @El_Vanja

Comment: What is the end goal here? Several forms, each filled with data from the database? Or something else?

Comment: no, i only want one column of each type, like voornaam, achternaam and initialen, now i've from every columns two.you see in the image.

Comment: As @El_Vanja already mentioned there is something odd. Seems like your `$fieldList` produces the field twice OR your `$dataList` contains the entires twice OR both. A simple fix could be `if (array_key_exists($value['name'], $list)) { continue; }` but this would still result in a bad pre-condition (your sql queries). Is it possible to add your raw-sql queries generated by `processing()` ?

Comment: It's already fixed

Comment: @PieterDijkstra are you planning to add an answer to inform the other's that your question got answered?

Comment: I'll add the answer when i'm free from work, in a couple of hours

Comment: After answering a few of your recent questions @Pieter I would have thought that either I would understand your application to some extent or that one of my answers would have already helped you to iron out your data problems.  Now I am looking at a new script of yours and there seems to be both things that don't make sense and things that are unexplained.  We don't know what `processing()` does, but we probably don't need to if you show us `var_export($data)`, `var_export($dataItem)`, and `var_export($fieldList)`.

Comment: @Pieter  The `foreach($fieldList as $key => $value)` is weird.  You are forcing uniqueness by assigning the same string as the key and the value.  Is this actually a necessary step?  Do you need to purge duplicate name values?  By extension, `foreach ($list as $key => $value)` it is useless to declare `$key` because the same value is already in `$value`.  There is a fair amount of redundancy in your `if` block, that can afford some sensible D.R.Y.ing out.  There is a disconnect between what you need (in the screenshot) and the data that you are offering.  Please edit.

Comment: Give me a moment and i'll show you. There is one kind of error in my new answer script. Because he looked at names instead of id's. Give me minutes and i'll update my answer for you

Comment: I've added the answer @mickmackusa

Comment: There remains a disconnect between between your scripts.  I have used my browser's find feature to search for `getDataListItems()` -- you have shown the function declaration, but nowhere have you actually used it.  This makes your question confusing.  If the incoming `$category` argument is an `int` then it makes no sense to call `trim()` on it.  Furthermore, you are using a PDO prepared statement (good), but you are injecting the variable directly into the query (not good) instead of using a placeholder.  Should be: `WHERE fields.category_id = ?` and `$sql->execute($category);` @Pieter

Comment: I still have no idea how `processing` behaves, so it is rather difficult to debug that part. @Pieter

Comment: Create a chat for this so we can discuss this in private. thanks! If your answer will help my question i'll give you the bounty